# RuntimeError: Failed to download geckodriver

Tags: geckodriver

I am getting below error.

> RuntimeError: Failed to download geckodriver archive: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.34.0/geckodriver-v0.34.0-win32.tar.gz

- Browser: Chrome
- OS: Windows
- geckodriver is already installed

After checking all available downloads here - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

For windows, it is in zip format and tried to change to .zip which resulted in below read error.

> tarfile.ReadError: not a gzip file

Can any of you please suggest a workaround?